# Dynamically add different version of css for different browsers using jquery or pure javascript

Tags: jquery, css

As you know, in order to make css3 work for different browsers, one has to use different versions of css. For example, to make background gradient possible, these are the css needed.

```
background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

My question is, how do I dynamically add these css to a div? I tried using css(map) method but it doesn't work. The last css will override the previous one. Worst still, css(map) doesn't work on filter.

Comment: Have you tried LESS for that?

Comment: Why not just put all of that into one CSS file that's always included? The way it's ordered now, old browsers will get the `rgb` rule, old Firefox will get the `-moz` rule, likewise for older Chrome/Opera/Safari/IE for `-webkit`, `-o`, and `-ms`, and then modern browsers supporting the standard get normal `radial-gradient`. Of course, then any IE browser that supports `filter` will get that. Is there an issue with how that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ain't pretty, but it seems to work:

```
$div.attr('style',"background: rgb(30,87,153); background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 );");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sw27eyay/1/